# Elasticdump and Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using elasticdump and got weird error

```
Mon, 14 Nov 2022 14:42:21 GMT | starting dump
Mon, 14 Nov 2022 14:42:22 GMT | got 10 objects from source elasticsearch (offset: 0)
Mon, 14 Nov 2022 14:42:22 GMT | sent 10 objects to destination file, wrote 10
Mon, 14 Nov 2022 14:42:22 GMT | Error Emitted => This and all future requests should be directed to the given URI.
Mon, 14 Nov 2022 14:42:22 GMT | Error Emitted => This and all future requests should be directed to the given URI.
Mon, 14 Nov 2022 14:42:22 GMT | Total Writes: 0
Mon, 14 Nov 2022 14:42:22 GMT | dump ended with error (get phase) => MOVED_PERMANENTLY: This and all future requests should be directed to the given URI.
```

It successfully moved 10 objects and stopped

Comment: What ES version and what elasticdump version?

Comment: ES 7.16, es-dump - latest (6.94)

Comment: Can you share the command you're running? It's because of a "302 Moved permanently" HTTP status

Comment: elasticdump \
  --input=xxxx   --input-index=dev_index \
  --output=test2.json

Answer (score 0):

`--input-index` is for a [different use case](https://github.com/elasticsearch-dump/elasticsearch-dump#notes).

Try with just `--input` like this

```
elasticdump --input=http://localhost/dev_index --output=test2.json
```